# I´m using phpexcel whit cakephp but have a error "this page not found" in localhost:

Tags: php, cakephp, phpexcel, cakephp-2.3

I have the error when load one cell but the page not load I work in localhost but show:
this page not found

this is my code:

my model Documento.php:

```
<?php
class Documento extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'documento';
}
?>
```

my controller DocumentosController.php:

```
<?php
class DocumentosController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','PhpExcel.PhpExcel');
    public $components = array('PhpExcel');

    public function index() {

        $this->set('documentos', $this->Documento->find('all')); 
    }

}
?>
```

my view index.ctp:

```
<?php  

App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel');
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007');

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("autor");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("autor");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("titulo del Excel");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Asunto");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Descripcion");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// define table cells

foreach($documentos as $documento){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue ('A2'.$i,'id');

}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Reporte');
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);

// close table and output
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="documento.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

//Creamos el Archivo .xlsx
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

Comment: Don't know if it's because this, but add `$this->layout = false` to your `index()` method, to avoid rendering a layout

Comment: thanks for you help but, not change nothing, show the page: "this page not found"... I dont now what happen, if maybe is the library or something when load the cell...

Comment: Then, are you sure your view is inside `View\Documentos`?

Comment: yes... sure is view/index.ctp  my view

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but is in `View\index.ctp` or `View\Documentos\index.ctp`?

Comment: sorry is View/Documentos/index.ctp...

Comment: Did you try to comment the last line and instead use Debugger::dump($documentos) ?